# Appcelerator - Add search bar into action bar on Android

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

I want to add on Android a search bar like in this photo. On iOS I've done this using Window titleControl but on Android I can't. I've only got add a search icon on the menu options. Any ideas? Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is possible and mentioned in Appcelerator Docs: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Android.SearchView